# How would mom have handled this

Tags: modal-verbs

> Father: Can't you just try sharing a room with your sister? Your mom
>   was always so good at this stuff. *I'd come home from work and
>   everything was always perfect.* **How would mom have handled this?**
>
> Daughter: She would have caught me before I moved into the garage. Mom
>   knew everything I did before I did it.
>
> Father: What is it honey?
>
> Daughter: It is just not fair. First, I lose my mom! Then grandma
>   leaves. Now even I lose my own room.
>
> Father: I know how much you girls miss your mother. Because I miss her
>   too. Very much. But you still got me.

1) I don't understand the use of "would" in the italic part.

2) Is the following implied from the bold part?
How would mom have handled this if she had been alive

Movie: Full House

Comment: Read this article (**Could have, should have, would have**): https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/could-have-should-have-would-have.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is correct. "How would mom have handled this if she were  alive?".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79567)

Comment: @VarunNair It does seem to answer the question. The asker wrote, "Is the following implied from the bold part? How would mom have handled this if she had been alive". The answer confirms that.